# Angularjs - Conditions inside 'ng-class'

Tags: angularjs

```
ng-class="{highlightRow: row.Note === 'Success'}"
```

If this highlights the rows whose *Note* field is *Success*, can I have a condition inside this `ng-class` to highlight rows where *Note* field is either *Success* or *Warning*?

Comment: `{highlightRow: row.Note === 'Success' || row.Note ==='Warning'}`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `ng-class="{highlightRow: (value === 'Success' || value ==='Warning')`

I gave `success` by default and after 3 seconds it changes to `Warning`, but the `highlightRow` remains same. **Pleas check below snippet and demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<style>
.highlightRow{
color: green
}
</style>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p ng-class="{highlightRow: value === 'Success' || value ==='Warning'}">{{value}}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.value = "Success";
     $timeout( function(){
            $scope.value = "Warning";
        }, 3000 );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above Code**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/n8HsvWX0g9WIV6QIFHQb?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this yet?

```
ng-class= "{'highlightRow' : row.Note === 'Success' || row.Note === 'Warning'}"
```